# TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/ in Django 2.0.2

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

when I try to execute the function, I am getting (TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/)
my templates folder is located at C:\Users\Rafik\Documents\myproject\env_mysite\Scripts\mysie\books\templates
python code is running fine but it says TemplateDoesNotExist

> views.py:
>
> def search(request):

```
error = False

if 'q' in request.GET:

    q = request.GET['q']

    if not q:

        error = True

    elif len(q) > 20:

        error = True

    else:

        books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)

        return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'books': books, 'query': q})

return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'error': error})
```

apps/urls.py:

> from django.conf.urls import url
>
> from books import views
>
> urlpatterns = [

```
url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
url(r'^search/$', views.search)
```

> ]

TEMPLATE settings.py

> TEMPLATES = [

```
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

> ]

Comment: Provide more information please, what is the view (CBV or generic one), relevant parts from settings.py and your folder structure please.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 3):

I am new to stackoverflow as an author, so please excuse me for not using the appropriate markup here. I run into the same error when working through the Django 2.0 tutorial (more specifically: in Tutorial03, after switching from loader.get_template() to shortcuts.render()). The following solution finally proved to work for me:

- In the TEMPLATES section of my settings.py, DIRS remains an empty list and APP_DIRS is set to True.
- In the render() statement, there is no path portion when specifying the template, just e.g. render(request, 'index.html', context)
- the template file must *directly* be located in the app/templates directory (not in /app/templates/app)

My enviroment is Django 2.0.2 with CPython 3.6.4 under Windows 10 (and cygwin). Hope this helps.